Any research on ODE $\frac{1}{\sin ^{N-2} \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin ^{N-2} \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta})=f(u)$?
I want to know if there is any research on ODE $$\frac{1}{\sin ^{N-2} \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\sin ^{N-2} \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta})=f(u)$$
with any boundary condition?
Actually I'm studying $$\Delta u = f(u)$$ on the upper half sphere in dimension $N$, for example, if I want to study the radial symmetric solution which only depends on the distance to the north pole which is $\theta$ in spherical Laplacian

Then I can rewrite the ODE as
$$
\frac{1}{\sin ^{N-2} \theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\sin ^{N-2} \theta \frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta}\right)=f(u)
$$
I know this ODE is complex but I still want to ask if there is any research on it.
Update: Sorry for my careless omission, I want to ask about the case when $f$ is nonlinear such as $$f(u)=e^u.$$
